# How to divided two input value from Bluetooth and show them in different TextView

Tags: android, bluetooth, textview, arduino

Can you suggest me how to manage to divide two values which i get from Arduino via Bluetooth. I am measuring two sensors and one of them i added number 10000, so now i am getting values in terminal like 540 10025, 540 10024,..... 
I added 10000 to one sensor to easier divided them. 
Now i want to show those two numbers in different TextView and remove 10000 from one.

this is how i get the number in on TextView

```
public class ArduinoReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {    
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String data = null;     
        final int dataType = intent.getIntExtra(AmarinoIntent.EXTRA_DATA_TYPE, -1);

        if (dataType == AmarinoIntent.STRING_EXTRA){
            data = intent.getStringExtra(AmarinoIntent.EXTRA_DATA);         
            if (data != null){
            mValueTV.setText(data + "°");
                alarm();
            }
....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you are receiving two different types of integers through the same broadcast receiver - one lower than 10,000 and the other higher. And you want to show them in two different TextViews. The code should look like

```
data = intent.getStringExtra(AmarinoIntent.EXTRA_DATA);
if (data != null)
{
    int value = Integer.parseInt(data);
    if (value >= 10000)
    {
        // put in one text view after substracting 10,000
        firstTextView.setText(Interger.toString(value - 10000) + "°");
    }
    else
    {
        // put in the second TextView
        secondTextView.setText(data + "°");
    }
}
```

Comment: It shows secondTextView but when it comes to firstTextView it crash. I get message: Error receiving broadcast in LogCat. If i am trying to show it in one TV it works.

Comment: Can you share your logcat messages?

Comment: 08-20 11:48:33.600: E/AndroidRuntime(8760): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error receiving broadcast Intent { act=amarino.intent.action.RECEIVED flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.prototipmbv.MainActivity$ArduinoReceiver@42f665e8

Comment: The problem was that i get float number in then function parseInt crashed.

Comment: Great ! Use ParseInt() with a try-catch block to avoid such a case.